# Android Studio - How to Remove YouTubePlayerListener (PierfrancescoSoffritti)

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, android-youtube-api

How am I able to remove YouTubePlayerListener in YouTubePlayerView?
Im using the **YouTube Player** of *PierfrancescoSoffritti*
this is GitHub link: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#youtubeplayerlistener

No matter how hard I try to understand it Im so confuse what to put inside the parenthesis of

> youTubePlayerView.removeYouTubePlayerListener();

---

**This is my Code:**

```
youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID, 0);
        }
    });
```

and I want to remove the YouTubePlayerListener when I click the **Button1**

Answer (score 0):

The following is clearly mentioned in the documentation so you should be good to go:

> A `YouTubePlayerListener` is used to intercept events emitted by a
> `YouTubePlayer`.
>
> During its existence a `YouTubePlayer` will constantly emit events, you
> can listen to them by adding a `YouTubePlayerListener` to it.
>
> ```
> youTubePlayer.addListener(YouTubePlayerListener listener);
> youTubePlayer.removeListener(YouTubePlayerListener listener);
> ```

Comment: Hello, I was asking what to put inside of youTubePlayerView.removeyouTubePlayerListener("?what to put in here?")???

Comment: Did you got the any solution? please help me. facing same issue.